# Parsing an XML file with Java issue

Tags: xml

I'm trying to get this XML file

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
<PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

To parse with this output

```
parsing cd_catalog.xml
Document root node is: CATALOG
 First CD Data:
Empire Burlesque
Bob Dylan
USA
Columbia
10.90
1985
 Second CD Data:
Hide your heart
Bonnie Tyler
UK
CBS Records
9.90
1988
 Last CD Data:
Unchain my heart
Joe Cocker
USA
EMI
8.20
1987
Total Number of CDs is: 26
```

I have this code below which does the parsing but it outputs "First CD Data" for every CD, I need to go "First CD data" "Second CD data" and "Last CD data".

```
    private static void printNodes() {


      Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
      System.out.println(root.getNodeName());

      //Get all CDS
      NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("CD");
      System.out.println("============================");

      for (int temp = 0; temp < 2; temp++)
      {
       Node node = nList.item(temp);
       System.out.println("");   
       if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
       {
          //Print each CD's details
          Element eElement = (Element) node;
          System.out.println("First CD data is : "    + eElement.getAttribute("TITLE"));
          System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("ARTIST").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("COMPANY").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("PRICE").item(0).getTextContent());
          System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("YEAR").item(0).getTextContent());



       }
      }

  }
```

My plan was to take the for loop i have down to 1 so it prints off all the first CD's data, then make another for loop for the next CD but i'm not sure how to find that CD in the array list and then what would i do for the last CD.

Comment: Your loop is explicitly printing "First CD data is : " every time - try changing it to choose a different string based on the loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

quite simplest,
convert your XML to JAXB class
use online convertor: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

try {

```
    File file = new File("cd_catalog.xml");  
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class);  

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
    Catalog cat= (Catalog) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  

    List<CD> list=cat.getCD();  
    for(CD cd:list)  
      System.out.println(cd.getArtist());  

  } catch (JAXBException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
  }
```